# React - Checking for a change of state every few seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React js, I want to call a function when a state is set to pending.

This state is only changed when the API call is completed which can take a number of seconds.

The flow is:

1. Initial API is called
2. State is set to pending
3. Secondary API is called but can take a number of seconds to set state to complete
4. When state is 'complete' I want to carry out a function.

How would you recommend ‘looping’ to check for this change of state every few seconds?

I have tried with componentDidUpdate() but haven’t had much luck.

Cheers

Edit:
To clarify - I'm waiting on an API call that takes a couple of seconds meaning I'd need to periodically check back.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add the relevant code for us to review. As it currently stands, your question is too vague for us to help you.

Comment: `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate` are called when your state changes, just use them.

Answer (score 0):

> How would you recommend ‘looping’ to check for this change of state every few seconds?

I wouldn't. I'd handle the completion of the API call. If it's asynchronous (as you imply), it will provide a way to be notified when it completes — it'll accept a callback, or return a promise, that sort of thing. Use that, rather than a timer and looping.

Comment: He probably knows that already, since he's setting the state based on what this call returns.

Comment: @Walk: I don't see any evidence of that in the question, given he/she is talking about using timer loops instead.

Comment: To clarify - I'm waiting on an API call that takes a couple of seconds meaning I'd need to periodically check back.

Comment: @A.Christou: That doesn't really clarify anything. If the API call is synchronous, then the next line of code is where you'd use the results. If it's asynchronous, it *will* provide a means of notifying you when it's done, as I said above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks very much for the replies. The initial question on my end wasn't great to begin and had little context.  


The API call is working and I am able to set state based off this with no problem.  


The issue I'm having is that when I call the API, it will take say, 5 seconds for the API attribute to update to my desired value. Because my call is setting state in much less time than that, I am unable to get the information that is updated 5 seconds after the API is called. I have to refresh the page to get the updated information.

Comment: @A.Christou: I have no idea what you mean by *"...it will take say, 5 seconds for the API attribute to update to my desired value..."* unless it's that it takes 5 secons for the API to do what you asked. Again, it's either synchronous (in which case nothing else can happen during those 5 seconds), or it's asynchronous (in which case it provides a way for you to know when the work is done, 5 seconds later).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `setState` a callback function.

**Example**

```
this.setState({ pending: true }, () => {
  console.log('State set completed for pending');
});
```